# copying a list to a new list - More efficient & Best Practice

Tags: c#

What is the appropriate way of copying a list to a new list?
And What is the most efficient way of copying a list to a new list?

By efficient, not code efficiency, more in the behind the scenes framework sense.

```
List<String>List2 = List.ToList();
```

**Or:**

```
List<String>List2 = new List<String>();
foreach (string item in List)
{
 List2.Add(item);
}
```

**Update:**

What about more efficient IL code?

Comment: Well your first example needlessly initializes `List2` then throws that initialization away. It should be just `List<String> List2 = List.ToList();`

Comment: Why do you not write a test and share the result with us?

Comment: Honestly, the performance difference between the two is going to be so small, I doubt you will notice.  Do with whichever one makes your code easier to read.

Comment: How big is your list? How often is it copied per second? Anything but _extreme_ answers to those questions means that the difference between any of the given answers is _trivial_. If you do have extreme answers for either of those, you may want to consider a different design or container other than `List<T>`. (EDIT: the only modification I might suggest would be to presupply the list size in your second example to avoid array resizing, but again, only really has a measurable effect for lists of relatively large size or massively frequently copying)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What ToList does (shortened):

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

What List ctor does (shortened):

```
public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    ICollection<T> collection2 = collection as ICollection<T>;
    int count = collection2.Count;
    this._items = new T[count];
    collection2.CopyTo(this._items, 0);
    this._size = count;
}
```

So the ToList() is much more efficient - it does allocate the space first and then copy all items in one step.

Comment: How is `ToList` more efficient if it goes ahead and calls the ctor?

Comment: Because it already allocates the new list in size to hold all items. While the second approach puts them one by one. List<T> isn't dynamic - once there are more items that its capacity its being reallocated, which is costly operation.

Comment: actually my bad - I thought you were comparing `ToList` and the `ctor` here, but you're not.  Sorry!

Answer (score 23):

Given that `List<T>` has an `IEnumerable<T>` constructor, I would prefer this form:

```
List<string> newList = new List<string>(otherList);
```

**Edit**

And as Ondrej points out in the decompiled code below, the constructor of `List<T>` preallocates the size of the array and copies the contents over.  This is going to be much quicker than creating a new list and then iterating over the other list adding items individually, especially as in your 2nd example you're not specifying how many items to preallocate.

Comment: If you look at the decompiled source, that is what `ToList` does.

Comment: I guess it's because you don't need to iterate through the content.

Comment: Out of "performance", does this constructor automatically initialize the new List to be of the proper length or does it do the dynamic resizing as it transfers elements over?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair If you see Ondrej's answer below, it preallocates the array with the size of the collection passed.

Comment: `List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)` just calls `List(IEnumerable<T> collection)` after a null check on the source.  And the List Constructor itself does a null check on the collection, so just calling the Constructor is more efficient as you skip the duplicate null check.  And both are potentially better than `foreach(...){ list2.Add(...)}` since the constructor will check to see if the collection implements ICollection<T>, and thus has a `.Count` property, which it can use to preallocate the array and then just `Array.CopyTo(...)`;

Comment: @Moo-Juice Thanks, didn't see that answer yet and I wasn't sure if it checked and casted as such. (I suspected it did, but wasn't positive)

Comment: This method is the most code efficient, however, since ToList takes an IEnumerable<T> it doesn't know its size so there is really no performance difference between your code and the other code examples.

Comment: @Casperah in the List constructor, it casts the `IEnumerable<T>` to an `ICollection<T>`, and thereby knows the size ahead of time.

Comment: I have looked at the contructor, it casts the IEnumerable<T> to ICollection<T> and construct its internal Array with the correct capacity and uses Array.CopyTo to copy the content.  All in all this may be the most efficient way to go.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`List<T>` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes `IEnumerable<T>`

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();

// fill list1

List<string> list2 = new List<string>(list1);
```

Comment: If you look at the decompiled source, that is what ToList does.

Comment: You don't want to look at decompiled code all the time, do you? I think this is what people would use for readability purpose.

Comment: In this particular case I am looking beyond code readability.

Comment: @oleksii But `ToList` seems quite straightforward. I think all cadrell0 is saying is that in terms of efficiency, there will be no difference given that `ToList` is doing the same thing you are.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of efficiency, the first is going to be faster. `List<T>`'s underlying implementation is an ArrayList, so there's a chance you'll have to resize the underlying array when you call `.Add`.

On the other hand, `.ToList` can determine the correct initial size of the new `List` and avoid the reallocation operation that the `foreach` technique suffers from.

With this in mind I'd recommend `.ToList`. Less code and it will be faster.

Here's a simple program you can run to verify that `ToList` is indeed faster:

```
void Main()
{
    List<int> items = new List<int>();

    items = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToList();

    CopyWithToList(items);
    CopyWithForeach(items);

}

public void CopyWithToList<T>(List<T> list) 
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    List<T> copy = list.ToList();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("CopyWithToList: {0}", sw.Elapsed);
}

public void CopyWithForeach<T>(List<T> list)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    List<T> copy = new List<T>();
    foreach (T item in list) {
        copy.Add(item);
    }
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("CopyWithForeach: {0}", sw.Elapsed);
}
```

Comment: Even if you supply the list with initial size to pre-allocate, it still slower. I suspect that really comes from the fact that the constructor call (which `ToList` uses) essentially performs an array copy whereas the `foreach` performs all the additional overhead of checking of the collection changed, grabbing the iterator, iterating, checking when calling `.Add()` if the underlying array is long enough, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Tests shows, that the best perfomance have the `.ToList()` method (for a list with 21474836 elements it runs in about 48 ms on a laptop Core i5 CPU).

Every other method is slower, and the method, using `.Add()` is the worst, while talking about perfomance.

Here is some test code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue / 100; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }

        TimeItAccurate(ListCopy_1, list, 10);
        TimeItAccurate(ListCopy_2, list, 10);
        TimeItAccurate(ListCopy_3, list, 10);
        TimeItAccurate(ListCopy_4, list, 10);
        TimeItAccurate(ListCopy_5, list, 10);
    }

    private static List<int> ListCopy_1(List<int> list)
    {
        var newList = list.ToList();

        return newList;
    }

    private static List<int> ListCopy_2(List<int> list)
    {
        var newList = new List<int>(list.Count);

        foreach (var i in list)
        {
            newList.Add(i);
        }

        return newList;
    }

    private static List<int> ListCopy_3(List<int> list)
    {
        var newList = new List<int>(list.ToArray());

        return newList;
    }

    private static List<int> ListCopy_4(List<int> list)
    {
        var newList = new List<int>(list.Count);

        newList.AddRange(list);

        return newList;
    }

    private static List<int> ListCopy_5(List<int> list)
    {
        var newList = new List<int>(list);

        return newList;
    }

    public static void TimeItAccurate<TIn, TResult>(Func<TIn, TResult> func, TIn argument, int iterationsCount)
    {
        #region Pre-heat
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var t = func.Invoke(argument);
        }
        #endregion

        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        var result = default(TResult);

        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterationsCount; i++)
        {
            result = func.Invoke(argument);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Result:\n{4}(...) == {0}\n\n{1} iterations done in {2} ms.\nAverage time: {3:f5} ms.",
            result,
            iterationsCount,
            stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
            stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / (double)iterationsCount,
            func.Method.Name);
    }
}
```

And the results:

```
Result (.ToList()):
ListCopy_1(...) == System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

10 iterations done in 474 ms.
Average time: 47.40000 ms.

Result (for-cycle with .Add()):
ListCopy_2(...) == System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

10 iterations done in 1896 ms.
Average time: 189.60000 ms.

Result (ctor with .ToArray()):
ListCopy_3(...) == System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

10 iterations done in 981 ms.
Average time: 98.10000 ms.

Result (.AddRange()):
ListCopy_4(...) == System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

10 iterations done in 959 ms.
Average time: 95.90000 ms.

Result (new List<int>(list)):
ListCopy_5(...) == System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

10 iterations done in 480 ms.
Average time: 48.00000 ms.
```

Comment: Your 3rd test is flawed.  Why are you calling `ToArray()` - just pass the list directly.

Comment: Just passing the list will be just the same, as we know from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17571821/1309740). I just wanted to show some range of variants how to do that copy operation.

Comment: then perhaps you can consider adding a "straight to `ctor`" as a 5th test for completeness.

Comment: I wonder why `ToList` averages out as a second faster when it itself uses the `ctor` version inside?

Comment: That's the question for me too. On 10 interations run `.ToList` is sometimes slower, but when I'm going up to 100 and 1000 iterations, `ctor` always loses.

Comment: I'm assuming this is being run in Release?

Comment: I dont see why the AddRange has to be that slow. Should be the same as ToList and new List in IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the two examples are identical, the .ToList() implements probably the later.

The best performance would be something like this:

```
List<String> list2 = new List<String>(list.Count);
foreach(String item in list)
    list2.Add(item);
```

The important part is to create list2 with enough capacity to hold its content.

If you don't need to modify the either list afterwards, the a reference copy is all you need:

```
List<String> list2 = list;
```

Comment: There are better ways to achieve this.

Comment: It is important to allocate enough space for the list by specifying a capacity in its constructor.  This way the list does not need to reallocate the list while adding items.

Answer (score 0):

Answers that uses `new` (including e.g. `ToList()`, `ToArray()` which internally use `new`) when you need a list copy, cause heap allocations & consequent garbage collection. Those are astoundingly bad ways to get "the fastest possible list copy". So you can safely ignore most of the answers here.

`new` your lists once off only, at your application startup, ensuring your lists are maximally sized.

```
int MAX_SIZE = 100000;
List<int> list1 = new List<int>(MAX_SIZE);
List<int> list2 = new List<int>(MAX_SIZE);
```

Then do this at runtime wherever you need a full copy of the list:

```
list2.AddRange(list1);
```

`List.AddRange()` uses `List.InsertRange()` which uses `Array.Copy()`  which uses an approach something like `memcpy` in C, i.e. it does bulk copies very fast.

The balance here will be choosing your `MAX_SIZE` carefully - not so big that it makes your copies slow, not so small that you exceed what your program is likely to need.

Comment: As an aside: Sadly (as of this date), `List<T>`s based on `stackalloc`'ed `Span<T>` do not (yet) exist, or we could temporarily allocate our secondary list on the stack, use it locally for useful things that list provides like `List<T>.Sort()`, and then have that list popped cheaply off the program stack, without heap GC, once the method scope concludes.