# Comparing Tuples

Tags: c#, list, sorting, tuples

So i'm trying to compare tuples here. Essentially I have a list of data that has been sorted in a particular way and I need to figure out how it has been sorted. To do that I have placed these arrays into tuples and sorted them in the possible ways for them them to be sorted. when I compare the tuples they are apparently correct when they should be. Tuple that should be sorted by Name Age and then weight is equal to the unsorted original information and yet it never actually changes Value to the correct value.

```
public string Solve(string[] name, int[] age, int[] weight)
    {
        string Value = "";


        var personDefault = new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length-1 ; i++)
        {
            personDefault.Add(new Tuple<string, int, int>(name[i], age[i], weight[i]));
        }

        var personSorted = new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>();
        personSorted = personDefault;

        personSorted = personSorted.OrderBy(s => s.Item1).ThenBy(s => s.Item2).ThenBy(s => s.Item3).ToList();
        if (personDefault.Equals(personSorted) == true)
            Value = "NAW";//Name Age Weight

        personSorted = personSorted.OrderBy(s => s.Item1).ThenBy(s => s.Item3).ThenBy(s => s.Item2).ToList();
        if (personDefault.Equals(personSorted) == true)
            Value = "NWA";//Name Weight Age

        personSorted = personSorted.OrderBy(s => s.Item2).ThenBy(s => s.Item1).ThenBy(s => s.Item3).ToList();
        if (personDefault.Equals(personSorted) == true)
            Value = "ANW";//Age Name Weight

        personSorted = personSorted.OrderBy(s => s.Item2).ThenBy(s => s.Item3).ThenBy(s => s.Item1).ToList();
        if (personDefault.Equals(personSorted) == true)
            Value = "AWN";//Age Weight Name

        personSorted = personSorted.OrderBy(s => s.Item3).ThenBy(s => s.Item2).ThenBy(s => s.Item1).ToList();
        if (personDefault.Equals(personSorted) == true)
            Value = "WAN";//Weight Age Name

        personSorted = personSorted.OrderBy(s => s.Item3).ThenBy(s => s.Item1).ThenBy(s => s.Item2).ToList();
        if (personDefault.Equals(personSorted) == true)
            Value = "WNA";//Weight Name Age
            /* 
        if (1 == 1)
            Value = "IND";//Indeterminate
        if (1 == 1)
            Value = "NOT";//None of the above
            */


        return Value;
    }
```

Comment: I think you alwas compare the list with itself. You have to do a copy of personDefault(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571621/copying-a-list-to-a-new-list-more-efficient-best-practice), not asign it to personSorted

Comment: tried| var personSorted = new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>(personDefault);
Didn't change anything

Comment: I think what you want is `SequenceEqual`  Equality for List<T> doesn't do an item by item comparison, it just uses the base Object.Equals which isn't going to be what you want

Comment: I've tried that to. I think I may have other problems that I'm not yet aware of here.