# Why an object is modified when I retrieve it from a container

Tags: c#, reference, containers

When I put a list in a [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8) and retrieve it later the content may be modified. Why ?

```
var list = new List<int> { 1 };
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<List<int>>();
queue.Enqueue(list);  // Put the list in the queue
list.Clear();         // Clear the list
if (queue.TryDequeue(out var originalList))
  Console.WriteLine(originalList.Count);  // output 0: the original list is empty !?
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: What is wrong with my question? i dont have more code and it dont work. So what can i say more.

Comment: Why are you locking before accessing the queue?

Comment: You can provide a compilable example.

Comment: "Count for objects in list = 0" - you clear the list after enqueuing a *reference* to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enqueue the list, it's passed by [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types), it's not a copy of the list but a reference to the object.

```
queue.Enqueue(list);  // put a reference of list into queue
```

Then you clear it.

```
list.Clear();  // clear list
```

Then you retrieve a reference to if from the stack.

```
if (queue.TryDequeue(out var originalList))
```

At this point, `originalList` and `list` are references to the same object.
`list` as been cleared, hence `originalList` is empty.

```
Console.WriteLine(originalList.Count); // Ouput 0
```

If you really want to keep the data in the queue, you have to create a copy of the list.
A short (and efficient) way to do it is to use [ToList()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.8), but you may consider [others options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571621/copying-a-list-to-a-new-list-more-efficient-best-practice).

```
var list = new List<int> { 1 };
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<List<int>>();
queue.Enqueue(list.ToList()); // enqueue a copy
list.Clear();
if (queue.TryDequeue(out var originalList)) // retrieve a ref to the copy of original data
    Console.WriteLine(originalList.Count);  // output 1
```

Personal advice: Copying a list may cost time and should not be done without thinking about it at least twice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a full example code in order to get a better response. But I have noticed an important mistake in your code:

`ConcurrentQueue`as the [documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8):

> Represents a thread-safe first in-first out (FIFO) collection.

So, you have to remove your `lock` calls

Comment: The same result when i do that.

Comment: Although in this case you get the same result, you are using wrong this class.